# Sync Google Cloud Datastore with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-datastore, microservices

I have Google Cloud Datastore as Single Point of Truth and I want to index data from it in dedicated service for reading, filtering a searching. For this purpose I am creating an ElasticSearch-based service.

And I am wondering if there is some simple way/library to keep ES synced with the Datastore or if I simply have to write a bridge and handle it on my own?

I will be using events so I only need a way of fetching the data from DS to ES. I will handle the deleting, creating and updating specific records via events but I want to avoid doing the complete syncing(when service instance comes up) on my own.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: What's up, Ivan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no way for that today. At least for 8 month of development with GCP, including Datastore, App Engine, Functions, Compute Engine, PubSub, I was not able to find much libraries for them. Including Elasticsearch indexing for Datastore out of the box. Today we are doing the same thing (indexing db entities in elasticsearch), and this is done as additional DB communication layer.

Comment: was trying to do the same thing can you please brief more on the same .. like how the data from datastore is sent to elasticsearch?

Comment: @MD5, You can write a decorator around datastore client that will send all required requests to ES. Or you can make a calls in required methods so in order to not use much of elastic resources.

Comment: Thanks will try that... was thinking other way round is it possible for ES to directly pull the data from datastore (obviously we will provide the required keys to connect to our datastore).